# Why is this DELETE query so slow on Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm writing some database upgrade scripts, and am running into a query that takes a lot longer than I think it should:

```
DELETE FROM TPM_TASK WHERE TASK_TYPE='System';
```

This query takes over an hour, and I'm curious what the culprit is.

The execution plan is:

```
DELETE STATEMENT    899.0   887 57793984    35481   1454721 899                             ALL_ROWS                                            
DELETE                                                      1   TPMDBO  TPM_TASK                                                        
TABLE ACCESS (FULL) 899.0   887 57793984    35481   1454721 1   TPMDBO  TPM_TASK    FULL    TABLE   ANALYZED    1
```

Running:

```
select count(1) FROM TPM_TASK WHERE TASK_TYPE='System';
```

The plan is:

```
SELECT STATEMENT    92.0    89  14527479    1   7   92                  ALL_ROWS                                            
SORT (AGGREGATE)                1   7   1           AGGREGATE                                                   
INDEX (FAST FULL SCAN)  92.0    89  14527479    35481   248367  1   TPMDBO  TPM_TASK_TASK_TYPE  FAST FULL SCAN  INDEX   ANALYZED
```

This query is quite fast and gives me 44,202 rows.  The total number of rows in the table is 71419.  Since I'm deleting over half the rows, I'm thinking Oracle isn't bother to use the index at all on the delete, which is fine.  A full scan of 71,000 rows should still only take a few seconds anyhow.

There are no triggers on this table.  There aren't any other tables that have FK constraints on this table, however there are a few views and SQL functions that use this table.  The only application that uses this database is our web server, which is shut down during the upgrade - so I don't think there's any locking issues going on.  Any other ideas?

Comment: The delete statement indeed does not use the index as you can see by the `TABLE ACCESS (FULL)` step (btw: please post the plans with the tab characters removed, currently the columns don't line up and it's practically impossible to read)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - But that should be fine right?  The WHERE clause returns over half the rows, using the index wouldn't really be a huge perf improvement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Hmm, Aqua Data Studio really screws up formatting when you copy and paste execution plans.

Comment: If there are foreign key references to that table, and the other tables have lot's of records, the delte query will be slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Baring in mind the considerations you gave, the only thing I can think of is some kind of `UNINDEXED REFERENCE CONSTRAINT` referring to this table. Try running [this script](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4530093713805#26568859366976) against the table, it should give you a report with any unindexed references it finds. There's certainly no reason why this operation should take close to this long.

Comment: Yea, there's 56 rows in that report.  So you're saying something is referencing `TPM_TASK` and there's no index on that, so it has to do a full table scan for every individual delete?

Comment: Ah, yes that was it!  There were actually two tables referring to the PK of `TPM_TASK` which were not indexed.  I created an INDEX on those, and then just manually deleted the rows that referenced the soon-to-be deleted rows in `TPM_TASK` (avoiding the cascading delete).  After this, the delete statement on `TPM_TASK` took about 10 seconds.  This is a *fantastic* example proving just because you don't directly query on a column doesn't mean you don't need an index on it.

Comment: @MikeChristensen - Glad I was able to help, I spend a lot of time optimizing Oracle queries and run into indexing & referencing issues regularly.

Comment: Excellent! But you said "There aren't any other tables that have FK constraints on this table"?

Comment: @wolφi Could be less obvious than FK constraints. Some kind of trigger on a table referencing another table, for example.

Comment: @wolφi - I did say that!  In Aqua Data Studio, if you click on *Dependencies*, these tables don't show up.  I'm not sure if that feature is broken (at least for Oracle), or just doesn't do what I was expecting it to do.  Maybe I'll go email them and ask.

Comment: FYI - I just found out Aqua Data Studio will show FK constraints from other objects, but you have to right click on the table and select *Table Properties*, then go to the *References* tab.